# Why did IBM decide to use 8 bits for EBCDIC?

Tags: ibm, ebcdic

Why did IBM decide to use 8 bits for EBCDIC?

7 bits per character seems reasonable, since `2^7 = 128 symbols` which is enough for all English letters and special symbols.

Comment: In some article they say the EBCDIC was designed for compatibility with the IBM 029 punch card codes: http://www.edwardbosworth.com/My3121Textbook_HTM/MyText3121_Ch10_V01.htm

Comment: ASCII is not sufficient.  For example, it has no 'cent' or 'logical not' (the one that looks like a horizontal bar with a right-hand vertical) character

Comment: "7 bits ought to be enough for anybody" ;)

Comment: @Vlad so EBCDIC is 8 bits since it should be compatible with IBM 029?

Comment: Note: EBCIDIC wasn't directly intended to be an encoding for "all English letters and special symbols." It evolved from an encoding of the various patterns of holes punched in Hollerith cards. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

Comment: 7 bits are not enough for English: we are fooled by ASCII. But there were huge discussion on deciding which characters to include. E.g. US cent symbol was not included, so now we never see it (so we think 7 bit is enough). Ellipsis, dashes, *European characters* were also common. US constitutions has also the long S. Symbols (and mathematical symbols *to write programs*) where also a huge part of discussion.

Answer (score 6):

> Why did IBM decide to use 8 bits for EBCDIC?

Because the /360 ISA defined a byte to consist of 8 bits - which in turn was chosen as it allows to store two decimal numerals (BCD) within a byte.

> 7 bits per character seems reasonable, since 2^7 = 128 symbols which is enough for all English letters and special symbols.

For one, there is not just English - a company like IBM for sure does not want to restrict their sales to only English speaking countries? And even then, its customers don't want to serve only them as well, right?

On a more practical side, when it came to printable characters EBCDIC did cover everything ASCII did (*1) while leaving plenty room for additional use cases.

Most important: **There is simply no sense in defining a character code that uses less bits than a character cell offers.**

---

*1 - At that point its important to keep in mind that IBM was a major proponent of ASCII - in fact, next to all terminal equipment used ASCII - there was never any dispute people nowadays assume.

Comment: Re, "no sense in defining a character code that offers less bits than..." I don't know about that. It might depend on how many different glyphs you can make room for on the drum or the chain of your line printer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm do not really get your point. What good is a 7 bit code if the unit a machine uses to handle characters (aka a byte) is fixed to 8 bit ? External codes, like printer or data transmission are a different issue, as they are defined by the media used - like ASCII being 7 bit for optimal line utilisation.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't understand what "code...uses less bits..." meant. I _assumed_ you were saying that if you had eight bits available in which to store each code point, then it would not make sense to define fewer than 256 of them. I, on the other hand, thought that there might have been a time—back before "interoperability" was a thing—when there would have been no reason to define code points for characters that the hardware was not able to display.

Comment: I'm afraid that the statement *There is simply no sense in defining a character code that uses less bits than a character cell offers* is too strong and simply untrue. Defining a 7-bit character code will allow for faster transmission over serial interfaces, regardless of the character cell size.

Comment: @LeoB. It might be helpful to read existing comments before adding another. Line codes are a different issue and follow different rules. After all, there are many different to be used. EBCDIC is about encoding within the computer, there is no advantage in using a specific line cone - in contrast, being independend allows to form a superset of line codes. Also, as long as either code can be handled with 8 bits, translating data between codes is a single machine instruction on a /360.

Comment: I've read the comments, that's why my point is that the bolded statement as written is overly broad and therefore wrong. "A character code" does not specify the purpose of the code. Moreover, the letter I in EBCDIC implies that EBCDIC is not only about encoding within the computer.

Comment: @LeoB. Not sure what retrospective arguing should do, but within the /360 world EBCDIC was always only used within the computing equipment. But since you think there would be a reason for using a 7 bit code with a machine handling bytes as 8 bit, could you name it? What is it good to not use the 8th bit?

Comment: "Interchange" includes communication between the CPU and the peripherals as well. Using a 7-bit code on a machine with 8-bit bytes allows to form/verify parity in the software, and improves throughput of serial communications by >10% (e.g. 8E1 vs 7E1).
Your bolded statement can be understood as "ASCII is nonsensical". Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: @LeoB. Not necessary. Interchange can as well mean between applications, isn't it? No sense in overinterpreting here. Also, there is no need to do a very  sopecial case, like parity checking, to be handled by software and in application space. This is what line buffers are about. As mentioned before in a comment you claimed to have read _" External codes, like printer or data transmission are a different issue, as they are defined by the media used"_  So again, please explain what good a 7 bit code would go to justify use _within_ a machine already using 8 bit bytes ?

Comment: Even if we're limiting ourselves to symbol processing, to start with, it would reduce the size of all transcoding tables, character property tables, lexer state transition tables, etc, from 256 elements to 128 elements? Is that enough to make sense?

Comment: @LeoB. No, as these are again rather special use cases. Not to mention that it, each of these would have to a add exception handling for input to these tables with one of the other 128 possible values - after all, a byte on a /360 has still 8 bit, doesn't it? 128 byte tables would result in quite inefficient code.

Comment: When RAM is at a premium, it is better to reduce the size of the tables. Checking that the  upper bit of a byte is not set is cheap. Again, by saying that a 7-bit encoding on an 8-bit byte machine does not make sense you're contradicting all history of ASCII-based systems.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, our DEC 2020 handled 36 bit words (no sub-word addressing), and 6-, 7- and 8-bit characters packed into words.

Comment: @LeoB. No, it isn't cheap, because it means that a string has to be handled by a loop, many times slower than the available translate instruction. Also, all of this is beside the main point: The /360 was made to store two 4 bit BCD in a byte - not easy with with 7 bit bytes, or is it? So a character had 8 bit, thus any character handling would be 8 bit, no matter how if the used character codes may fit in 7 bit. There is simply no gain to make.

Comment: @vonbrand, Not just 6, 7, and 8: The PDP-10\* instruction set had instructions for accessing packed arrays of "bytes" that could be any size from 1 bit per byte to 36 bits per byte. Doesn't have any bearing on why EBCDIC is an 8-bit code though. (\* Your "DEC 2020" was a [PDP-10 in orange paint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DECSYSTEM-20).)